# Anaconda Runtime Error "NameError: name 'python' is not defined"

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm having a strange error with Python and Tensorflow. When I try to run my code, I'm having this message but I'm pretty sure I have installed Tensorflow and it was working fine previously.

- My OS is Windows 10 64-Bit
- I installed Python through Anaconda (Python 3.6.6)
- I installed Tensorflow with both pip and Anaconda GUI (neither worked)

I downloaded the code from [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb). The first time I tried it worked and for the rest of the tries, it didn't work. I tried too many things (like a new environment, different versions of Tensorflow etc but I cannot make it work).

This is my Anaconda Spyder output:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

# Import TensorFlow >= 1.9 and enable eager execution
import tensorflow as tf

#tf.enable_eager_execution()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import unicodedata
import re
import numpy as np
import os
import time

print(tf.__version__)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-22177e76b58e>", line 4, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 594, in <module>
    del python

NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

And this is my Anaconda prompt output:

```
(google_nmt) C:\Users\ismetb\Desktop\google_nmt>python google.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3086, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3114, in _initialize_master_working_set
    for dist in working_set
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3114, in <genexpr>
    for dist in working_set
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2637, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2174, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Anaconda3\envs\google_nmt\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2109, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Desktop\google_nmt\google.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(tf.__version__)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'
```

This also happened in one of my colleague's laptop too. The first time he tried me made it work and the code never run for the rest of the tries.

What might be the problem?

Comment: ??? have you tried to remove the "del python" line? looks very suspicious to me

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There's no such text in my code. It must be in `tensorflow\__init__.py` package

Comment: I know, but since it doesn't work, you could try to comment that. If it works, well, it works...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it didn't work at first try and gave this error: `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'` Then I commented `del core` line along with `del python` and it seems to work now. If you have that file, can you please check whether it exists in your file too?

Comment: I don't have it here, but I remember installing tensorflow at work (using pip & manual wheel installs since we don't have internet directly on our machines, so it took a while) and it imported properly. Using python 3.5 (anaconda)